# IIS URL Rewrite with Abort action is not aborting the request

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I am trying to abort some URL patterns when it comes to my server/application. I have the below URL Rewrite in place. But I am seeing those request are not aborted under the worker process.

If the URL is something like `www.example.com/search/?q=abc\&page=abc\&contenttype=all` I want to abort that request immediately.

```xml
<rule name="Abort Request" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{URL}" pattern="\/search\/\?q=" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="AbortRequest" />
</rule>
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules FRT can reveal to you what happens under the hood.

Comment: In addition to generating logs via FRT. You can simply test if pattern="search" aborts if it works. You can also specify blocking rules based on the query string if it works properly. Otherwise, you need to use FRT to see what happened that caused the abort operation not be executed.

Comment: Thanks @TengFeiXie I had to split-up the condition as URL + Query String to make it works.